# Ansible playbook to get value from some dictionary keys

Tags: ansible

I'm writing a playbook to collect data from some network devices, but now I'm having difficult to filter these data. I need just values from some keys.

This is the full data I'm getting:

```
       "license": {
    "response": {
        "@status": "success",
        "result": {
            "licenses": {
                "entry": [
                    {
                        "authcode": "11111111",
                        "description": "Feature A",
                        "expired": "no",
                        "expires": "September 10, 2020",
                        "feature": "Feature A",
                        "issued": "September 10, 2016",
                        "serial": "96765555555"
                    },
                    {
                        "authcode": "222222222",
                        "description": "Feature B",
                        "expired": "no",
                        "expires": "September 14, 2020",
                        "feature": "Feature B",
                        "issued": "September 14, 2016",
                        "serial": "77777777777"
```

From this, I just need the feature and expires information, like this:

```
                        "expires": "September 10, 2020",
                        "feature": "Feature A",
                        "expires": "September 14, 2020",
                        "feature": "Feature B",
```

I'm trying to do with regex like below, but I cannot get the full value and its marching just the first key (there are two with the same name):

- set_fact:
     feature: "{{ (license_output.stdout | regex_search('feature(.+?) '))}}"
     expires: "{{ (license_output.stdout | regex_search('expires(.+?) '))}}"
- debug:
     msg: "{{ feature }}"
     msg: "{{ expires }}"

My current code:

- set_fact:
     feature: "{{ (license_output.stdout | regex_search('feature(.+?) '))}}"

  expires: "{{ (license_output.stdout | regex_search('expires(.+?) '))}}"
- debug:
     msg: "{{ feature }}"
     msg: "{{ expires }}"

That is the expected result:

```
                        "expires": "September 10, 2020",
                        "feature": "Feature A",
                        "expires": "September 14, 2020",
                        "feature": "Feature B",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as if you're getting a JSON response in `license_output.stdout`. There's no reason to try parsing this with a regular expression when you can just look up values directly in the json data.  Consider:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    license_output:
      stdout: |
        {
          "license": {
            "response": {
              "@status": "success",
              "result": {
                "licenses": {
                  "entry": [
                    {
                      "authcode": "11111111",
                      "description": "Feature A",
                      "expired": "no",
                      "expires": "September 10, 2020",
                      "feature": "Feature A",
                      "issued": "September 10, 2016",
                      "serial": "96765555555"
                    },
                    {
                      "authcode": "222222222",
                      "description": "Feature B",
                      "expired": "no",
                      "expires": "September 14, 2020",
                      "feature": "Feature B",
                      "issued": "September 14, 2016",
                      "serial": "77777777777"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg:
          feature: "{{ item.feature }}"
          expires: "{{ item.expires }}"
      loop: "{{ (license_output.stdout|from_json).license.response.result.licenses.entry }}"
```

This would output:

```
    TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
    ok: [localhost] => (item=Feature A) => {
            "msg": {
                    "expires": "September 10, 2020", 
                    "feature": "Feature A"
            }
    }
    ok: [localhost] => (item=Feature B) => {
            "msg": {
                    "expires": "September 14, 2020", 
                    "feature": "Feature B"
            }
    }
```

It's not clear exactly what you want to do with these values; you're using `set_fact` in your example, but since there are multiple features, you can't use a single variable named `feature` or `expires`.  One possibility is something like this:

```
- set_fact:
    "expires_{{ item.feature.lower().replace(' ', '_') }}": "{{ item.expires }}"
  loop: "{{ (license_output.stdout|from_json).license.response.result.licenses.entry }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.feature }}"

- debug:
    msg: "Feature A expires on {{ expires_feature_a }}"
```

This would create variables with names like `expires_feature_a` and `expires_feature_b`. The above example would output:

```
TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Feature A expires on September 10, 2020"
}
```

Another example might be to build up a dictionary that maps feature names to expiration dates:

```
- set_fact:
    features: "{{ features|default({})|combine({item.feature: item.expires}) }}"
  loop: "{{ (license_output.stdout|from_json).license.response.result.licenses.entry }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.feature }}"

- debug:
    msg: "Feature {{ item.0 }} expires on {{ item.1 }}"
  loop: "{{ features.items() }}"
```

This would output:

```
TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=[u'Feature B', u'September 14, 2020']) => {
    "msg": "Feature Feature B expires on September 14, 2020"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[u'Feature A', u'September 10, 2020']) => {
    "msg": "Feature Feature A expires on September 10, 2020"
}
```

Comment: Glad it worked!  If this solved your problem, you can click the checkbox to the left of the answer to indicate that you accept the answer.